# Destructive UIContextualAction gives bad animation

Tags: swift, uitableview

Implementing a 'swipe do clear' gives a bad animation when tapping the clear button. Sliding all the way through the left gives a normal animation though.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let clearAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Clear") { (action, view, completion) in
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        completion(true)
    }
    clearAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearGray
    let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [clearAction])
    return swipeConfiguration
}
```

It's as if the delete starts a second time. When I leave out `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` the animation is perfect, but then the table view crashes when adding or deleting rows later (row count doesn't match with before and after situation).

Slomo:

[image: Swipe to delete]